# Simulate v-if directive in custom directive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I need to destroy element in custom directive like v-if. (Forbid item creation if the condition fails.)

I trying this

```
export const moduleDirective: DirectiveOptions | DirectiveFunction = (el, binding, vnode) => {
  const moduleStatus = store.getters[`permissions/${binding.value}Enabled`];
  if (!moduleStatus) {
    const comment = document.createComment(' ');
    Object.defineProperty(comment, 'setAttribute', {
      value: () => undefined,
    });
    vnode.elm = comment;
    vnode.text = ' ';
    vnode.isComment = true;
    vnode.context = undefined;
    vnode.tag = undefined;

    if (el.parentNode) {
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(comment, el);
    }
  }
};
```

But this option does not suit me. It does not interrupt the creation of the component.

[image]

this code removes an element from DOM, but not destroy a component instance.

Comment: way not using the render option of vue component?

Comment: @perymimon yes. I need to destroy an element without initialization.

Comment: @Mgorunuch, were you able to find a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not checked this but [from doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) it should look like this.
probably I will edit it later with a more specific and correct answer

```
Vue.directive('condition', {

 
  inserted(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode){
    /* called when the bound element has been inserted into its parent node
      (this only guarantees parent node presence, not necessarily in-document). */

     if (!test){ el.remove() }
  }


  update(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode ){
    /* called after the containing component’s VNode has updated, but possibly before 
       its children have updated. */

     if (!test()){ el.remove() }
    //or you can try this, changed the vnode
    vnode.props.vIf = test();
  }
}
```

Or in short

```
Vue.directive('condition', function (el, binding) {
  if (!test){ el.remove() }
})
```

> Apart from el, you should treat these arguments as read-only and never modify them. If you need to share information across hooks, it is recommended to do so through element’s dataset.

Comment: I might be wrong, but with all due respect, I don't think this really answers the question. The OP mentioned that the desired functionality is to prevent the DOM element to be created if the condition is not met (e.g. prevent an image from loading, similar to what would happen if using a `v-if` directive). This answer removes the element, but the image resource would have been already loaded.

Comment: I can second @Charmander. It works visually, not even flickering, but any resources that would have been created, would remain in memory, and maybe even using compute resources.